# Kubuntu 16.10 - VirtualBox not working correctly

Tags: virtualbox, kubuntu

Since I upgraded from 16.04 to 16.10 VirtualBox is not working properly.  I followed a few other suggestions online and made baby step progress.  When I try to run a VM I get an error for any of them usually containing message to run:

```
/sbin/vboxconfig
```

When I run that it gives me an error of:

```
vboxdrv.sh: Building VirtualBox kernel modules.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Look at /var/log/vbox-install.log to find out what went wrong.
```

Here is what's in [vbox-install.log](http://pastebin.com/qRuiukRR) (some of content here):

```
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
Makefile:185: *** Error: unable to find the sources of your current Linux kernel. Specify KERN_DIR=<directory> and run Make again.  Stop.
make KBUILD_VERBOSE=1 SUBDIRS=/tmp/vbox.0 SRCROOT=/tmp/vbox.0 CONFIG_MODULE_SIG= -C /lib/modules/4.8.0-27-generic/build -j4 modules
make[1]: warning: -jN forced in submake: disabling jobserver mode.
test -e include/generated/autoconf.h -a -e include/config/auto.conf || (        \
echo >&2;                           \
echo >&2 "  ERROR: Kernel configuration is invalid.";       \
echo >&2 "         include/generated/autoconf.h or include/config/auto.conf are missing.";\
echo >&2 "         Run 'make oldconfig && make prepare' on kernel src to fix it.";  \
echo >&2 ;                          \
/bin/false)
mkdir -p /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions ; rm -f /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_versions/*
make -f ./scripts/Makefile.build obj=/tmp/vbox.0
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/linux/.SUPDrv-linux.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include  -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -Iubuntu/include  -D__KERNEL__ -fno-pie -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -fno-pie -no-pie -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -DCONFIG_X86_X32_ABI -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SSSE3=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CRC32=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fno-var-tracking-assignments -pg -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=strict-prototypes -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -I/lib/modules/4.8.0-27-generic/build/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxdrv/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxdrv/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DSUPDRV_WITH_RELEASE_LOGGER -Wno-declaration-after-statement -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-pie  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"SUPDrv_linux"'  -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxdrv"' -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/linux/.tmp_SUPDrv-linux.o /tmp/vbox.0/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.SUPDrv.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include  -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -Iubuntu/include  -D__KERNEL__ -fno-pie -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -fno-pie -no-pie -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -DCONFIG_X86_X32_ABI -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SSSE3=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CRC32=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fno-var-tracking-assignments -pg -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=strict-prototypes -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -I/lib/modules/4.8.0-27-generic/build/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxdrv/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxdrv/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DSUPDRV_WITH_RELEASE_LOGGER -Wno-declaration-after-statement -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-pie  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"SUPDrv"'  -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxdrv"' -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_SUPDrv.o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrv.c
  gcc -Wp,-MD,/tmp/vbox.0/.SUPDrvGip.o.d  -nostdinc -isystem /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/include  -I./arch/x86/include -I./arch/x86/include/generated/uapi -I./arch/x86/include/generated  -I./include -I./arch/x86/include/uapi -I./include/uapi -I./include/generated/uapi -include ./include/linux/kconfig.h -Iubuntu/include  -D__KERNEL__ -fno-pie -Wall -Wundef -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -Werror-implicit-function-declaration -Wno-format-security -std=gnu89 -fno-pie -no-pie -mno-sse -mno-mmx -mno-sse2 -mno-3dnow -mno-avx -m64 -falign-jumps=1 -falign-loops=1 -mno-80387 -mno-fp-ret-in-387 -mpreferred-stack-boundary=3 -mskip-rax-setup -mtune=generic -mno-red-zone -mcmodel=kernel -funit-at-a-time -maccumulate-outgoing-args -DCONFIG_X86_X32_ABI -DCONFIG_AS_CFI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SIGNAL_FRAME=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CFI_SECTIONS=1 -DCONFIG_AS_FXSAVEQ=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SSSE3=1 -DCONFIG_AS_CRC32=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX=1 -DCONFIG_AS_AVX2=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA1_NI=1 -DCONFIG_AS_SHA256_NI=1 -pipe -Wno-sign-compare -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -fno-delete-null-pointer-checks -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -O2 --param=allow-store-data-races=0 -Wframe-larger-than=1024 -fstack-protector-strong -Wno-unused-but-set-variable -Wno-unused-const-variable -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-optimize-sibling-calls -fno-var-tracking-assignments -pg -mfentry -DCC_USING_FENTRY -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wno-pointer-sign -fno-strict-overflow -fconserve-stack -Werror=implicit-int -Werror=strict-prototypes -Werror=date-time -Werror=incompatible-pointer-types -DCC_HAVE_ASM_GOTO -include /tmp/vbox.0/include/VBox/SUPDrvMangling.h -I/lib/modules/4.8.0-27-generic/build/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxdrv/ -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxdrv/include -I/tmp/vbox.0/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux -D__KERNEL__ -DMODULE -DRT_OS_LINUX -DIN_RING0 -DIN_RT_R0 -DIN_SUP_R0 -DVBOX -DRT_WITH_VBOX -DVBOX_WITH_HARDENING -DSUPDRV_WITH_RELEASE_LOGGER -Wno-declaration-after-statement -DCONFIG_VBOXDRV_AS_MISC -DRT_ARCH_AMD64 -DVBOX_WITH_64_BITS_GUESTS -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-pie  -DMODULE  -DKBUILD_BASENAME='"SUPDrvGip"'  -DKBUILD_MODNAME='"vboxdrv"' -c -o /tmp/vbox.0/.tmp_SUPDrvGip.o /tmp/vbox.0/SUPDrvGip.c
```

**EDIT: ADDITIONAL INFO (requested)**

Output of **dkms status**

```
rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg: added
virtualbox, 5.1.6, 4.8.0-27-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Output of **dpkg -l *linux-*|grep ii**

```
ii  linux-base                         4.0ubuntu1           all          Linux image base package
ii  linux-firmware                     1.161                all          Firmware for Linux kernel drivers
ii  linux-generic                      4.8.0.27.36          amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
ii  linux-headers-4.8.0-27             4.8.0-27.29          all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 4.8.0
ii  linux-headers-4.8.0-27-generic     4.8.0-27.29          amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 4.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic              4.8.0.27.36          amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-21-generic       4.4.0-21.37          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.8.0-27-generic       4.8.0-27.29          amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-21-generic 4.4.0-21.37          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.8.0-27-generic 4.8.0-27.29          amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.8.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-generic                4.8.0.27.36          amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-libc-dev:amd64               4.8.0-27.29          amd64        Linux Kernel Headers for development
ii  linux-sound-base                   1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5 all          base package for ALSA and OSS sound systems
ii  syslinux-common                    3:6.03+dfsg-14       all          collection of bootloaders (common)
ii  syslinux-utils                     3:6.03+dfsg-14       amd64        collection of bootloaders (utilities)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was that my PATH environment variable was malformed.  Correcting this and re-installing VirtualBox solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

before you run this again, run:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` dkms
```

This will install all kernel headers or dependencies you need.

Comment: Says everything is installed or newest version.

Answer (score 0):

The command needs to be run as root, so type this:

```
sudo /sbin/vboxconfig
```

The latest version of Virtualbox is 5.1. If you're running with version 4.3 or older, you should get at least version 5.0.

Lastly, if you're running with any dkms kernel modules, you will have to turn off `secure boot` in your BIOS so that unsigned kernel modules will load properly in 16.10.

Comment: Version is 5.1.  I did run /sbin/vboxconfig as root.  Cant I sign the modules?

Comment: Yes, you *could* sign the modules, but it is kind of a pain. Search AskUbuntu for signing kernel modules for info on how to do that. Are you still having problems with the vboxconfig command? If so, edit your question to include the `terminal` output of `dkms status` and `dpkg -l *linux-*|grep ii`.

Comment: Ok updated post..

Comment: Everything looks ok there. There is one partially installed dkms module for rtl8812au. And you **will** have to have `secure boot` turned off in your BIOS. Virtualbox is at 5.1.10, so you might wish to update to see if that helps you. Otherwise it looks like you've got some other kernel configuration problem that's over my head.